# Stripe - PaymentIntent requires a payment method issue in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, payment-gateway

I'm trying to integrate stripe in my project but I'm getting "**PaymentIntent requires a payment method**". The status code of payment in logs is 200. But in payment dashboard it is showing Incomplete and the reason is "**The customer has not entered their payment method.**"

[image: payment mode]

**Below is my stripe backend code**

```
exports.StripePayment = (req, res) => {
  const { amount, token } = req.body;
  const idempotencyKey = uuid(); 
  return stripe.customers
    .create({
      email: token.email,
      source: token.id,
    })
    .then((customer) => {
      stripe.paymentIntents
        .create(
          {
          
            amount: amount, 
            currency: "INR",
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            customer: customer.id,
            receipt_email: token.email,
            shipping: {
              name: token.card.name,
              address: {
                line_1: token.card.address_1,
                line_2: token.card.address_2,
                city: token.card.address_city,
                country: token.card.address_country,
                postal_code: token.card.address_zip,
              },
            },
          },
          { idempotencyKey }
        )
        .then((result) => {
          console.log("Result", result);

          return res.status(200).json(result);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });
};
```

Need help to fix. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behavior. The code you shared is only creating a Payment Intent, it is not progressing the intent through its [lifecycle](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/paymentintents/lifecycle).

Currently you are not providing an already created Payment Method, or a way for a customer to provide their payment method details. That will need to be added in order for Stripe to process a payment.

Creating a Payment Intent is only the first piece of a Stripe integration. This guide that Stripe provides walks through everything that is required to process a payment with their service, and is a great starting point for building an integration:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements

That guide will walk you through the remaining pieces that need to be built, including providing a UI for your customers to provide their payment method details, and confirming the Payment Intent.